# Skeleton: A simple, floating, responsive navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to create a simple, floating and responsive navigation bar while using Skeleton boilerplate.

It should be nothing more than a logo align to the left of container and a few menu anchor links aligned to the right. Position of it should be fixed while scrolling the site's content, while staying in Skeleton's responsive grid. [Exactly like here](http://www.diano.xyz/).

Natural way of doing this would be something like this for me.

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 5rem">
      <div class="two columns">
        <!--LOGO-->
      </div>
      <div class="ten columns" style="text-align: right;">
        <!--MENU-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The problem is that by setting **position: absolute**, div loses its ability to  divide into columns. Also, the links aren't clickable. Can anyone suggest a working solution? Having a hamburger menu icon on mobile would be an ideal extension, so if anyone knows the simplest way to do this, I would love to hear it out.

Thanks in advance!